# SQLite3: Unexpected wrappers in column names when SELECTing from (subqueries)

Tags: sqlite

I'm working with `SQLite3 in .cpp` and I'm using a `std::map<std::string, special_variant_type>` to store rows. All's good but I found that column names seem to keep wrappers when I `SELECT` from `(subqueries)`.

Compare these queries:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `sqlite_master` WHERE `type`='table'; // works as I expected
```

and *(pick any)*:

```
// do not work as I expected but might work as expected...
SELECT `name` FROM (SELECT `name` FROM `sqlite_master` WHERE `type`='table');
SELECT [name] FROM (SELECT `name` FROM `sqlite_master` WHERE `type`='table');
```

**ISSUE**: First one brings undecorated column names. So, the column name is `name`. For the second one, which selects from a subquery, the column name is untouched. Returns `backticks, square brackets [], double quotes "`... any name wrapper that should be... IMO, discarded.

**Is this expected behavior?** Seems inconsistent, either keep wrappers or discard them...

**PS**: *I'm now discarding them when I'm pairing the column maps, still... I'm wondering if this is right...*

**PPS**: *It happens in both the sqlite3 library and Navicat client.*

**Quick Solution**: 3.7.14 is broken. Update your client to a new version! Replace DLLs inside 3rd party software (but keep a backup copy just in case) that have this issue also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be consistent:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table test(x);
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> SELECT `name` FROM `sqlite_master` WHERE `type`='table';
name
----------
test
sqlite> SELECT `name` FROM (SELECT `name` FROM `sqlite_master` WHERE `type`='table');
name
----------
test
```

Anyway, SQLite makes no guarantees about column names.

To enforce column names in results, use `AS` to define aliases.

The most reliable way to access columns is by their index, thus avoiding problems with formulas or duplicate column names.

Comment: Great :) Updated the DLL in the SQLite client and now it works properly. Think it was a bug but google failed me on this one. Have to recompile the one I'm using (3.7.14) also as it was fixed in 3.7.15.